# FTCS Solution of the Wave Equation - Issues with Vpython

Tags: python, physics, vpython

> I am attempting to make an animation of the motion of the piano string
> using the facilities provided by the vpython package. There are
> various ways you could do this, but my goal is to do this with using
> the curve object within the vpython package. Below is my code for
> solution of the initial problem of solving the complete sets of
> simultaneous 1st-order equation. Thanks in advance, I am really
> uncertain as to where to start with the vpython animation.

```
# Key Module and Function Import(s):
import numpy as np
import math as m
import pylab as py
import matplotlib
from time import time
import scipy

# Variable(s) and Constant(s):
L = 1.0       # Length on string in m 
C = 1.0       # velocity of the hammer strike in ms^-1 
d = 0.1       # Hammer distance from 0 to point of impact with string
N = 100       # Number of divisions in grid
sigma = 0.3   # sigma value in meters 
a = L/N       # Grid spacing
v = 100.0     # Initial velocity of wave on the string
h = 1e-6      # Time-step
epsilon = h/1000

# Computation(s):

def initialpsi(x):
    return (C*x*(L-x)/(L**2))*m.exp((-(x-d)**2)/(2*sigma**2)) # Definition of the function

phibeg = 0.0     # Beginning - fixed point 
phimiddle = 0.0  # Initial x 
phiend = 0.0     # End fixed point
psibeg = 0.0     # Initial v at beg
psiend = 0.0     # Initial v at end 

t2 = 2e-3     # string at 2ms 
t50 = 50e-3   # string at 50ms
t100 = 100e-3 # string at 100ms
tend = t100 + epsilon

# Creation of empty array(s)
phi = np.empty(N+1,float)
phi[0] = phibeg
phi[N] = phiend
phi[1:N] = phimiddle
phip = np.empty(N+1,float)
phip[0] = phibeg
phip[N] = phiend

psi = np.empty(N+1,float)
psi[0] = psibeg
psi[N] = psiend
for i in range(1,N):
    psi[i] = initialpsi(i*a)
psip = np.empty(N+1,float)
psip[0] = psibeg
psip[N] = psiend

# Main loop
t = 0.0
D = h*v**2 / (a*a)
timestart = time()
while t<tend:

    # Calculation the new values of T
    
    for i in range(1,N):
        phip[i] = phi[i] + h*psi[i]
        psip[i] = psi[i] + D*(phi[i+1]+phi[i-1]-2*phi[i])
    
    phip[1:N] = phi[1:N] + h*psi[1:N]
    psip[1:N] = psi[1:N] + D*(phi[0:N-1] + phi[2:N+1] -2*phi[1:N])
    phi= np.copy(phip)
    psi= np.copy(psip)
    #phi,phip = phip,phi
    #psi,psip = psip,psi
    t += h

    # Plot creation in step(s)
    if abs(t-t2)<epsilon:
        t2array = np.copy(phi)
        py.plot(phi, label = "2 ms")
    if abs(t-t50)<epsilon:
        t50array = np.copy(phi)
        py.plot(phi, label = "50 ms")
    if abs(t-t100)<epsilon:
        t100array = np.copy(phi)
        py.plot(phi, label = "100 ms")
```

Answer (score 0):

See the curve documentation at

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/curve.html

Use the "modify" method to change the individual points along the curve object, inside a loop that contains a rate statement:

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/rate.html